# find the function exponential

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $ \lim_{ x\rightarrow a } f(x)=1$   and   $ \lim_{ x\rightarrow a } g(x)=\infty$

then is it true that

**$\lim_{ x\rightarrow a } f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)-1)g(x)}$**

I have checked this result for some limits and this holds well. Moreover I want to know how to prove this , But I have no idea about how to prove this. I think if it is true then we need to apply L hospital's rule if we assumed the  differentiability of the function..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true.

Since $f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp\bigl(g(x)\log\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)$,\begin{align*}\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}&=\lim_{x\to a}\exp\bigl(g(x)\log\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\bigr)\\&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\log\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\right).\end{align*}So, the question is: is the later limit equal to to $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\bigl(f(x)-1\bigr)$? Well,$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\bigl(f(x)-1\bigr)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\log\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\frac{f(x)-1}{\log\bigl(f(x)\bigr)}.$$But$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=1\Longrightarrow\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-1}{\log\bigl(f(x)\bigr)}=1.$$